# PixiJS Sprite not loading

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I've seen this question asked many times here already, but no replies to those posts helped me out: I'm trying to load a Sprite using the PixiJS engine, but it's not showing up despite it being recognised and loggable using **console.log()**. What am I doing wrong?

I've followed the tutorial from this URL:

https://github.com/kittykatattack/learningPixi#introduction

My code is as follows:

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>TITLE HERE</title>

        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style/style.css'>'
        <script src="js/pixi.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/init.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script>
            init();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**init.js**

```
var sprites = {};
var stage = new PIXI.Container();
var renderer;

function init(){
    createCanvas(288, 288, true);
}

function createCanvas(width, height, autoResize){
    //Create the renderer
    renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(width, height);
    renderer.autoResize = autoResize;
    renderer.view.setAttribute("id", "canvas");

    //Add the canvas to the HTML document
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);
    newSprite("assets/tilesheet.png", "tilesheet");
}

function newSprite(src, name){
    var texture = PIXI.Texture.fromImage(src);
    var sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);

    sprites[name] = sprite;
    stage.addChild(sprites["tilesheet"]);
    renderer.render(stage);
}
```

And just in case

**style.css**

```
body{
    background-color: #a9a9a9;
}

#canvas{
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 0.5em 0.5em 0 0 #777;
}

/* <TABLET> */
@media (min-width: 61.5rem){
    #canvas{
        width: 25em;
        height: 25em;
        box-shadow: 1em 1em 0 0 #777;
    }
}

/* <DESKTOP/TV> */
@media (min-width: 80.0rem){

}
```

This is my folder layout:

```
Project
  |-assets
  | \-tilesheet.png
  |-js
  | |-init.js
  | \-pixi.min.js
  |-style
  | \-style.css
  |-index.html
```

I hope someone can help me out.

### UPDATE

The code now works as it should. Based on feedback by *themoonrat* (accepted answer), the code now looks like this:

```
var sprites = {};
var masks = {};
var stageWidth = 288;
var stageHeight = 288;
var spriteWidth = 32;
var spriteHeight = 32;
var gridWidth = stageWidth/spriteWidth;
var gridHeight = stageHeight/spriteHeight;

var stage = new PIXI.Container();
var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(stageWidth, stageHeight);

function init(){
    renderer.view.setAttribute("id", "canvas");
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);

    for(var x = 0; x < gridWidth; x++){
        for(var y = 0; y < gridHeight; y++){
            newSprite('assets/tilesheet.png', 'tilesheet'+(x+y), x*spriteWidth, y*spriteHeight);
        }
    }

    sprites['tilesheet2'].position.x = 32;
    sprites['tilesheet2'].position.y = -32;

    console.log(sprites);

    // start updating
    update();
}

function newSprite(src, name, x, y){
    var texture = PIXI.Texture.fromImage(src);
    var sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);

    sprite.anchor.x = 0;
    sprite.anchor.y = 0;

    sprite.position.x = x;
    sprite.position.y = y;

    sprites[name] = sprite;
    stage.addChild(sprite);
}

function update() {
    requestAnimationFrame(update);

    renderer.render(stage);
}
```

The main difference is the inclusion of the **update()** function. Where, as *themoonrat* suggested, the **requestAnimationFrame()** is situated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only rendering the screen once, and the manner in which you are using pixi is to let pixi request to load the image rather than supplying a preloaded image.

So the point at which you render, just after creating the sprite, the request to load the image has only just occurred. Pixi can't render a sprite with a texture that hasn't finished loading.

If you put the render part within a contently called requestAnimationFrame , then the image would be rendered as soon as it had loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've managed to get it working. I'll post the new code in my original post.